# Does Googlebot crawl elements' attribute tags?

Tags: web-crawler, attr, google-crawlers

Does anyone know if Google will give weight to content in an element's attribute tags?

Is there any documentation supporting or disproving this? Or does the content *need* to be *visible*?

For example, is this not recommended (the data in the attributes will display later on the page using javascript):

```
<div class="myclass" 
    info="here is info about this subject"
    tags="here are tags"
    bio="here is my biography">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far a I know, element attributes are not indexed.  For instance, try searching a website (using site:) for an email address that you know is not displayed and is only in the mailto: attribute.  Google won't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I`m not sure what you mean by "gives weight" (do you mean SEO-wise?)
But Google and other SEs will crawl micro-data and use it for SERP results.

There is an accepted syntax for that, which you can find here http://schema.org.
Google and Bing/Yahoo will recognize and use it, and I think that other will as well (if not now than in the future, as this is the current standard)

If you are asking about the SEO implication than, based on personal experience I can say that:

A. This will improve Click-Through rate and thus help you SEO by maximizing potential of your current SERP position and by improving future rankings, as more visitors will help SEO in a number of direct and inderect ways (more traffic = more social signals, more organic links and etc...)

B. Providing more info to SEs is usually a very good thing. I saw improvement after implementing micro-data elements, but I also did it while engaging in other SEO practices so I really can say just how much of the growth was inspired solely by micro-data...